# Why undefined variable: email in send email laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

My code is like this :

```
public function handle(UserRegisteredEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->data;
        $name = $data['name'];
        $email = $data['email']; //tri@gmail.com

        Mail::send('emails.welcome', ['name' => $name], function($m){
            $m->to($email)
              ->subject('Transaction Details');
        });
    }
```

When executed, there exist error like this :

```
Undefined variable: email
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$email` variable is not recognized inside the mail closure function, you must explicitly pass it to the closure function using the `use` keyword like this:

```
public function handle(UserRegisteredEvent $event)
{
    $data = $event->data;
    $name = $data['name'];
    $email = $data['email']; //tri@gmail.com

    Mail::send('emails.welcome', ['name' => $name], function($m) use ($email) {
        $m->to($email)
          ->subject('Transaction Details');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While using function closure you need to use `use` to use a variable inside.

Try this:

```
Mail::send('emails.welcome', ['name' => $name], function($m) use ($email) {
            $m->to($email)
              ->subject('Transaction Details');
        });
```